# Session. Variable won't pass at the next page

Tags: php, session, variables

So I'm about to pass a variable at a second page. I tested the session at the top of my index page for me to know if session contains a variable. Like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$UserID = $_SESSION['CustNum'];
$UserN = $_SESSION['UserName'];
echo "$UserN";
?>
```

It's totally ok for the index page. It really prints the username. But when it comes to the next page where I'll pass the variable I tried the same code to see if the session contains something. But then, there's none. Help please. Also, these codes are both above my codes, above all else.

Comment: BTW: don't: `echo "$UserN";` but `echo $UserN;`

Comment: can you post your code for next page?

Comment: He writes it is the same code ...

Comment: Don't hide `E_NOTICE` from error reporting. Notices are an awesome tool rather than an annoyance.

Answer (score 3):

Where is:

```
$_SESSION['CustNum'] = 'xxx';
$_SESSION['UserName'] = 'yyy';
```

?

Comment: It's in the index page - if($numrows === 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error()); // fetch associated: get function from a query for a database
    $dbpass = $row['PassWord']; // read password of inputted user from the query.
    $dbuser = $row['UserName']; // read username from the query
    $dbactive = $row['Active']; // read if user is active
    $dbid = $row['CustNum'];
    
    if($UserP == $dbpass){
     if($dbactive == 1){
     //set session information
     $_SESSION['CustNum'] = $dbid;
     $_SESSION['UserName'] = $dbuser;
  
     }

Comment: @user1717305 have you started the session on another page using `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes.The codes I posted above are the exact ones at my next page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare a `session_start()` on your other page ?

And you need to initialize `$_SESSION['UserName']`somewhere.

Just like this `$_SESSION['UserName'] = "my_username"`

Comment: Yes. I'm sure about the session start and I also initialized a variable inside the$_SESSION['UserName']

Answer (score 0):

please try this method

in the first page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

session_start();

$_SESSION['CustNum']='12345';

$_SESSION['UserName']='sivanthi';
```

in the another page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['CustNum'];

echo $_SESSION['UserName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment and code:

```
if($numrows === 1){ $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
// fetch associated: get function from a query for a database
$dbpass = $row['PassWord']; // read password of inputted user from the query.
$dbuser = $row['UserName']; // read username  from the query
$dbactive = $row['Active']; // read if user is active $dbid = $row['CustNum'];

if($UserP == $dbpass){ if($dbactive == 1){ //set session information
    $_SESSION['CustNum'] = $dbid;
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $dbuser;
}
```

..i suppose this: `if($UserP == $dbpass){ if($dbactive == 1)` is `false`. Check it.